# How to select a gameobject from a UI list and do something with it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of gameObjects(NPCs) instantiating on a UI scrollable panel. I want to be able to click on their name and assign them to the building for example. here's what I have so far:

```
 HumanPool playerPool;

 [SerializeField] GameObject PlayerInfo;

 [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI playerName;

 [SerializeField] Transform SpawnPoint;

 void Start()
 {
     playerPool = FindObjectOfType<HumanPool>();
 }

 void updateListOfHumans()
 {
     SpawnPoint.DetachChildren();

     for (var i = 0; i < playerPool.Humans.Count; i++)
     {

         Vector3 pos = new Vector3(0, 0, SpawnPoint.position.z);

         playerName = PlayerInfo.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();

         playerName.text = playerPool.Humans[i].name;

         GameObject SpawnedItem = Instantiate(PlayerInfo, pos, SpawnPoint.rotation);

         SpawnedItem.transform.SetParent(SpawnPoint, false);
     }
 }
void OnMouseDown()
 {
     updateListOfHumans();
 }
```

I'm pretty sure that when I click on a playerName (child of a button) there should be an onClick() function that will do something. But I have no idea how to get that specific ID of a NPC and how to target him/her.

Here's also the relevant code from HumanPool:

```
List<Human> humans = new List<Human>();
public List<Human> Humans { get { return humans; } }
```

Humans are generated in a pure C# constructor class:

```
public class Human {
public string name;

public Human(string name)
{
    this.name = name;
}}
```

Should I add an ID variable in a constructor class and target clicked NPC with that?

My biggest problem here is how to tell the next method which NPC is chosen from a list and and that he/she should go work in that building.

Sorry for the possibly bad explanation but I really hope it makes some sense of what I'm trying to do here... Quite new with Unity so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you are using a [`UI.Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) component.

In that case there is indeed the [`onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) event you could simply add a callback to like e.g.

```
var human = playerPool.Humans[i];
var button = spawnedItem.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
button.onClick.AddListener(() => OnClickedHuman(human));
// You also want to do this rather on the spawned item, not the prefab btw
var text = spawnedItem.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
text.text = human.name;
```

and then have

```
private void OnClickedHuman (Human human)
{
    // Do what you want with human
    Debug.Log($"Clicked on {human.name}!", this);
}
```